# Selected value should not pick from the array_rand

Tags: php, arrays

Below php code I have selected "Neo" so Neo should not pick in the random selected. And another 2 value should print.

```
  <?php
    $input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
    echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
    echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
    ?>
```

And my array is Multi-dimentionnal array here is sample

```
array(1) { ["data"]=>  array(301) { [0]=>  array(2) { ["name"]=>  string(10) "Some Name" ["id"]=>  string(9) "5000213929" }
```

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to stop it picking "Neo"?

Comment: Yes but in Multi -dimensional array my sample one is simple array

Answer (score 1):

How do you know what "has been selected"? Is it in a variable? You will need to know that in order to unset the value from the array using [array_search](http://www.php.net/array_search)

```
unset($input[array_search('Neo', $input)]);
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
```

Which should unset Neo thus making it not an option to be used in the randomization. There are probably better ways to do this, but this is one way. And of course, if you do have a way to determine if Neo was selected, you would use that variable in place of 'Neo'.

Comment: I am getting NULL since my array is 2 dimensional array